# What may cause an Error 401 in an Spring MVC Application?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jsp

I have a Web Application built with JSP and Spring MVC that I didn't, but I'm currently in charge of it's source code.

When I test the application redirecting to most pages, it gives me a Error 401 (Unauthorized).

I searched along the application what may cause this, with no avail.

The only clues I have are the web.xml file and the mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml, that tells me the correct redirections and the exception handlers.

The web.xml page contains `<security-constraint>` tags containing the pages allowed for each user and all troubled pages are among the `<url-pattern>` tags inside each `<security-constraint>`.

However, none of the pages tells nothing about unauthorized pages.

Even I try to debug the ManagedBean class related to each one of those pages, but the error page is displayed before I can debug any line of code. I can only debug the Managed Bean's constructor and only when the application is deployed.

If you want an example or the content of some files. Let me know and I will give them to you.

Here are fragments of mvc-dispatcher-servlet.htm:

```
<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass"
              value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/paginas/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>
<bean name="/bloqueoindividual.htm"
      class="cl.claro.aplicaciones.webberr.controler.BloqueoIndividual">
     <!-- DOESN'T WORK. ERROR 401 -->
</bean>
<bean name="/bloqueomasivo.htm" class="cl.claro.aplicaciones.webberr.controler.BloqueoMasivo"   >
    <!--WORKS-->
</bean>

 <bean id="handlerExceptionResolver" class="cl.claro.aplicaciones.webberr.exception.ExceptionHandler"  >
   <!-- from ExceptionHandler -->
   <property name="ajaxErrorView" value="ajaxexception" />
   <property name="ajaxDefaultErrorMessage" value="${ajaxErrorMessage}" />
   <property name="ajaxShowTechMessage" value="false" />

   <!-- from SimpleMappingExceptionResolver -->
   <property name="defaultErrorView" value="checked"/>
   <property name="exceptionMappings">
      <props>
         <prop key="java.lang.RuntimeException" >unchecked</prop>
      </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<!-- Message resource bundle and locale -->
<bean id="messageSource"
class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource"  >
   <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
   <property name="basenames">
      <list>
         <value>classpath:message</value>
      </list>
   </property>
   <property name="fallbackToSystemLocale" value="false" />
</bean>

<bean id="localeResolver"
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.SessionLocaleResolver"  >
   <property name="defaultLocale" value="es" />
</bean>

<bean id="localeChangeInterceptor"
class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor"  >
   <property name="paramName" value="lang" />
</bean>
    <!-- End of resource bundle -->

    <!-- DISABLE CACHE DE PAGINAS -->

<mvc:interceptors>
   <mvc:interceptor>
      <mvc:mapping path="/**"/>
      <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.WebContentInterceptor"  >
         <property name="cacheSeconds" value="0" />
         <property name="useExpiresHeader" value="true"/>
         <property name="useCacheControlHeader" value="true"/>
         <property name="useCacheControlNoStore" value="true"/>
         <property name="alwaysUseFullPath" value="true"/>
      </bean>
   </mvc:interceptor>
</mvc:interceptors>
```

EDIT: As Akshay Mishra requested, I searched the application for any filter that would be applied to the pages. I found 2 filters.

1. One filter is a class that implements the interface `javax.servlet.Filter`, and hence overrides it's doFilter method as follows:

```
public static final String TXID_HEADER = "X-TXID";    

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain fc) throws IOException, ServletException {
        String path = ((HttpServletRequest) servletRequest).getRequestURI();
        if (path.startsWith(((HttpServletRequest) servletRequest).getContextPath() + "/resources/")) {
            //no aplicar txid a contenido estatico
            fc.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);
            return;
        }

        long t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();

        try{            
            String txID = ((HttpServletRequest)servletRequest).getHeader(TXID_HEADER);
            if (txID == null) {
                txID = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
            }
            ThreadContext.put("txid", txID);

            HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest)servletRequest;

            log.info("Peticion recibida: metodo=[{}] url=[{}] desde=[{}]", request.getMethod(), request.getRequestURI(), request.getRemoteAddr());

            HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse)servletResponse;
            response.setHeader(TXID_HEADER, txID);            
            response.setCharacterEncoding(CharEncoding.UTF_8);            
            fc.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);
        }
        finally{
            long t2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
            log.info("Peticion atendida en {} ms", t2-t1);
            ThreadContext.remove("txid");            
        }
    }
```

2. The second filter is at web.xml and only filters the extension allowed for the pages and redirections:

```
<filter>
   <filter-name>ResponseOverrideFilter</filter-name>
   <filter-class>org.displaytag.filter.ResponseOverrideFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
   <filter-name>ResponseOverrideFilter</filter-name>
   <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<filter-mapping>
   <filter-name>ResponseOverrideFilter</filter-name>
   <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: please check if any filter is getting applied

Comment: @akshay-mishra, I edited the description with your request. I hope this helps. Regards.